# How can the scrollbar be filled to the height of canvas? (grid based)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I placed the scroll bar in the second window. But the scrollbar is not as the height of canvas, it is very small. And only the buttons work. How do I make it as the height of the canvas?

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk



def on_window1():

    top = tk.Toplevel()
    top.wm_geometry("794x470")
    top.title('Optimized Map 1')


    frame = tk.Frame(top)
    frame.grid(row=3, column=0)

    canvas1 = tk.Canvas(top, width=400, height=280)
    canvas1.grid(row=0,column=200)

    for i in range(40):
        l3 = tk.Label(canvas1, text="Number of Rectangles:" + str(i))
        canvas1.create_window(50,21*i, window=l3, anchor=tk.NW)

    myscrollbar= tk.Scrollbar(top,orient="vertical",command=canvas1.yview)
    myscrollbar.grid(row=0,column=200)


    #l4 = tk.Label(canvas1, text="Number of Rectangles:")
    #canvas1.create_window(50,21, window=l4, anchor=tk.NW)

window = tk.Tk()


b1 = tk.Button(window, text="Next", command=on_window1)
b1.grid(row=0, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `grid` geometry manager does not automatically expand widgets to take up all the window space available to them.

You can use the `sticky` attribute to tell the widget which edges of the "cell" it should stick to:

```
myscrollbar.grid(row=0,column=200, sticky="NS")
```

Adding the above line in place of your `grid` call will resolve this.

---

For reference, the four edges of the "cell" are all named after the four cardinal directions (North, East, South and West) where N represents the top edge, E the right edge, S the bottom edge and W the left edge.

You can combine these together in the attribute declaration by adding up to all four of them as a string in any order.

Comment: This worked but only the buttons work and not the bar itself.

Comment: That's a different question. If you need an answer to that, ask a new question.